# How to call a Django Rest Framework API's POST method from Django Web Application when having foreign keys?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework

I have created 3 Models and 3 Serializers, 3 Viewsets in DRF Rest API.
1)Department Model : id,name
2)Country Model : id,name
3)Employee Model : id,firstname,lastname,title,Department-> Foreign Key,Country -> foreign Key

I have also created 3 serializers, one for each of the above models.

```
class Department(models.Model):
    DeptName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    LocationName=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.DeptName
    
class Country(models.Model):
    CountryName=models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.CountryName
    
# Create your models here.
class Employee(models.Model):         
    FirstName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    LastName=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    TitleName=models.CharField(max_length=30)           Department=models.ForeignKey("Department",default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="Departments")
    Country=models.ForeignKey("Country",default=0,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="Countries")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FirstName  

# Serializers
class DepartmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model= Department
        fields="__all__"         

class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):    
    class Meta:
        model= Country
        fields="__all__" 
        

class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):        
    class Meta:
        model= Employee
        fields="__all__" 

class DepartmentsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Department.objects.all()
        serializer_class = DepartmentSerializer   

class CountriesViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Country.objects.all()
        serializer_class = CountrySerializer   


class EmployeeViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EmployeeSerializer
```

##Now I want to insert records into Employee Table from Django Web Application (i.e) My Front end.
So I created 3 Models on client side too, 1 Model Form and 1 view in Django.

1. I have recreated 3 models on django client application, by taking the same code from DRF models.

2)I created FORM as below.

```
class EmployeeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

3)My View code
API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8000/api/viewsetemployees/"

#my post view

```
def employee_create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmployeeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create employee using DRF API
            response = requests.post(API_BASE_URL, data=form.cleaned_data)
            if response.status_code == 201:  # Created
                return redirect('getallemployees')
            else:
                # Handle error, e.g., display error message
                pass
    else:
        form = EmployeeForm()

    return render(request, 'drfconsumerappdemo/EmployeeInsert.html', {'form': form})
```

4.My Template code :

```
<body>
        
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <table class="table">
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
    </form>
</body>
```

when I access the employee_create view, i am getting below error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTa4b.png)

I was running DRF API On 8000 and Django App on 8001.
If i remove foreign keys from Models in my django app, form is getting rendered without any error.
I would like to see, 2 dropdown lists i..e 1 for country and 1 for department.

When i browse the restapi in browser, all is working well.

Comment: Please check the database of your Django client-side project. The error says there is no Department table in the database (on the client side). I hope you did run makemigrations and migrate commands in the client project after copying the models from the API project.